# NetBeans 7 Java Compile on Save with large project

Tags: compiler-construction, netbeans-7

I have a Java project with thousands of source code files.  I frequently encounter ClassNotFoundExceptions at runtime for classes for which I'm providing Java source code.  I do not experience this problem when I disable Compile on Save, but it's a useful feature and I'd like to have it enabled.

Is there a way that I can indicate to NetBeans "I know you think these files are already compiled, but schedule them for compilation (or I want you to re-compile them) anyway"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans should compile files once they are saved; failure to do so is a bug and is not a condition an end user should be trying to work around.

However, it is possible to create custom build scripts which import build.xml and override `-pre-compile-single` to define one or more source code files to be compiled.